# 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' when inserting data into Azure SQL Database table from Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to learn Azure IoT. What i am trying to is to send MQTT message to IoT Hub. And from IoT hub, i am using Streaming Analytics to output the data into SQL Database. But currently in Streaming Analytics Output, i have this error:

> [9:12:30 AM] Source 'OUTPUTSQL' had 1 occurrences of kind 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' between processing times '2019-05-23T01:12:30.5631321Z' and '2019-05-23T01:12:30.5631321Z'.

This is the data that i am trying to save

> {"ActionBy":"admin","ActionDate":"2019-05-22T16:00:00.0000000","Topic":"IoT","Message":"Hello World","QoS":"1","EventProcessedUtcTime":"2019-05-23T00:19:31.8287610Z","PartitionId":0,"EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2019-05-23T00:19:31.7170000Z","IoTHub":{"MessageId":null,"CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionDeviceId":"hartaMQTT-Device01","ConnectionDeviceGenerationId":"636936650733289038","EnqueuedTime":"2019-05-23T00:19:31.6820000Z","StreamId":null}}

I think the error is in IoTHub part.

This is the table in Azure Sql Server that i am trying to save:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IoTMQTT](
[EventID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ActionBy] [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
[ActionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Topic] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[Message] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[QoS] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[EventProcessedUtcTime] [datetime] NULL,
[PartitionId] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
[EventEnqueuedUtcTime] [datetime] NULL,
[IoTHub] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

What is the problem? Is it the datatype? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Azure SQL Server can not convert the  date "2019-05-23T00:19:31.8287610Z" to datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azrue SQL Database can convert "2019-05-23T00:19:31.8287610Z" to `datetime2` , `smalldatetime`, `time`, `date`, except `datetime`. Here is the error massage:
[image]

According your data , I think the datatype `datetime2` best for you.
[image]

Please modify your table, alter ActionDate, EventProcessedUtcTime, EventEnqueuedUtcTime columns to `datetime2`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Leon, 
I have the same problem but even after converting that to datetime2, it still gives the same error. 

OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' between processing times '2019-09-30T06:00:01.3315876Z' and '2019-09-30T06:00:01.3396220Z'...

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Hi @VivekAnanthan, you can post a new problem in Stack overflow with more details like Mru.

Comment: @VivekAnanthan In my case it was field which I was not provided but it was not nullable on db side. This is strange because field itself is not a `datetime` type, but the error message suggested issue with dates.